# Testing ActionMailer views in a Rails engine

Tags: actionmailer, minitest, rails-engines

I have a [rails gem/engine called `how_slow`](https://github.com/normalocity/how_slow/tree/12-mailer) that contains a view for my embedded ActionMailer subclass. When the gem is installed in an application the view is triggered and an email is sent. However, in the tests (I'm using minitest) the view doesn't get picked up or is inaccessible such that a call to:

```
HowSlow::Mailer.metrics_email.body.to_s
```

...returns an empty string (`""`) rather than the content of the email, as I intend it to.

The same call inside an app that uses a prerelease version of the gem/engine does, indeed, return the content of the text email as I would expect.

Am I missing something in terms of getting engine views to be visible to tests inside the gem/engine itself?

**Example:**

Inside an app that contains the current version of the gem on [this branch](https://github.com/normalocity/how_slow/tree/12-mailer) I get (I've broken up the line breaks for you so it's easier to read):

```
 > HowSlow::Mailer.metrics_email.body.to_s
=> "Slowest 12 requests, sorted by total_runtime:
   --------------------
   2013-06-22T11:42:21-05:00 :: sections/show    270 / 12 / 249
   2013-06-21T22:50:21-05:00 :: log_books/index  263 / 23 / 225
   2013-06-22T11:42:18-05:00 :: log_books/index  257 / 24 / 217
   2013-06-22T11:42:21-05:00 :: log_books/show   58 / 9 / 0
   2013-06-22T11:42:24-05:00 :: sections/show    56 / 4 / 14
   2013-06-22T11:42:20-05:00 :: log_books/index  39 / 11 / 27
   2013-06-22T11:42:26-05:00 :: log_books/index  38 / 12 / 25
   2013-06-22T11:42:31-05:00 :: sections/show    38 / 5 / 30
   2013-06-22T11:42:25-05:00 :: sections/show    28 / 4 / 20
   2013-06-22T11:42:28-05:00 :: sections/show    21 / 4 / 14
   2013-06-22T11:42:32-05:00 :: sections/show    20 / 3 / 12
   2013-06-22T11:42:28-05:00 :: log_books/show   5 / 1 / 0


   Counters sorted by alpha_asc:
   --------------------"
```

The view in question is here: https://github.com/normalocity/how_slow/blob/12-mailer/app/views/how_slow/mailer/metrics_email.text.erb

In the test framework, however, a call to `HowSlow::Mailer.metrics_email.body.to_s` returns `""` (empty string).